# How to make a custom Navigation bar in swift without using the default Navigation Bar provided by navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift

I wanted to make my own custom navbar in swift. Is there any way to implement this without using navigation controller's navbar.

Comment: maybe you can create UIView and place it on the top ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom UIView using a Xib, and then anywhere in your storyboard that you want to use your custom navbar you can drag a uiview, constrain it and then change the class of the UIView to your custom UIView class

Answer (score 0):

Try this code maybe its work for you

```
let navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: 44))
view.addSubview(navBar)

let navItem = UINavigationItem(title: "SomeTitle")
let doneItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.done, target: nil, action: #selector(doneAction:))
navItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneItem
```